# How should I plant and grow Crosnes?

Tags: planting, perennials, root-vegetables

I've heard that [Crosnes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stachys_affinis) is a good crop to grow, and was wondering how to plant/grow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De Wilde, co-owner of Harmony Valley Farm in Veroqua, Wisconsin has advised:

> You can plant the tubers in fall or early spring, in full sun and in any soil that drains reasonably well.  Once planted, the tubers need a steady supply of moisture until harvest to make a crop. It is easy to detect when they start to produce, the plants grow very shallowly, so you can see the ground crack and heave when the tubers start to swell.

(Reported at [Mother Earth News](http://www.motherearthnews.com/real-food/learn-all-about-crosnes-zmaz04fmzsel).)

[Incredible Vegetables](http://www.incrediblevegetables.co.uk/how-to-grow-chinese-artichokes/) advises:

> Being hardy things tubers can be planted out between October and April. Alternatively you can keep your tubers in trays or pots of slightly damp compost in a light place and leave them to sprout. You will see leaves appearing and when the plants are about 3 or 4 inches tall you can plant them out. Slugs do like the plants when small, so getting them going in pots first ensures that they can survive pests until they have got established. Plant about 25cm apart and a 7.5cm deep in rows of 45cm.

[*Stachys affinis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stachys_affinis) is "easy to grow". [Plants For A Future](http://www.pfaf.org/user/Plant.aspx?LatinName=Stachys+affinis) has:

> **Propagation**
>
> Seed - sow spring in a cold frame. Prick out the seedlings into individual pots when they are large enough to handle.
>   If sufficient growth has been made, it is possible to plant them out
>   during the summer, otherwise grow them on in pots for their first
>   summer, leaving the tubers in the pots to overwinter in a cold frame
>   and then plant out in late spring when in active growth. Seed is
>   rarely if ever produced on plants growing in Britain. Division. The
>   tubers can be harvest and replanted at any time whilst they are
>   dormant. They do start into growth fairly early in the year so it is
>   better to have moved them by the end of March[K].
>
> **Cultivation details**
>
> Prefers a well-drained soil in a sunny position[16]. Thrives in an ordinary garden soil[1], preferring one
>   that is not too heavy[16, 33]. It grows best in a soil that has been
>   well fed and does not dry out in the growing season[16]. Plants seem
>   to withstand even water-logged conditions in the winter[206]. The
>   Chinese artichoke is occasionally cultivated for its edible tubers,
>   they are planted out in March and harvested from October onwards[1,
>   58, 61]. Although top growth is killed back by frost, the tubers are
>   very hardy and can be left in the ground over winter to be harvested
>   as required[200]. It is virtually impossible to find all the tubers,
>   there are always some left behind that will grow the following
>   season[K]. Plants are very tolerant of high summer temperatures[206].
>   The tubers begin to sprout at temperatures above about 5°c[206].
>   Plants take 5 - 7 months to develop their tubers[206].

and various feedback.